Just installed Ubuntu 24.04.01 and ran sudo apt update. Got 4 errors
I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 from iso file downloaded from Ubuntu site on bootable Thumb Drive flashed with balenaEtcher. First thing I did was open terminal & run sudo apt update . I got 4 errors:


Err1: http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease Temporary failure resolving **archive.ubuntu.com**
Err2: http:/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease Temporary failure resolving **security.ubuntu.com**
Err3: http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease Temporary failure resolving **archive.ubuntu.com**
Err4: http:/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease Temporary failure resolving **archive.ubuntu.com**


Four 'W' warnings duplicating these messages were listed at the end and a fifth 'W' warning stating:
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Is there something I missed in the install? I can try a clean install again if I missed an important step or I can go ahead and upgrade. I usually run Kali and Debian Linux, so Ubuntu shouldn't be too different. I'm writing this on Kali running on a Raspberry Pi 5 with 2 32" monitors & a 2TB SSD (!).

It seems that you are not connected to internet.

Kali is irrelevant to this post. Please edit it out to prevent confusion.

New machine with Windows 11 installed - never booted until install of Ubuntu. Had Ethernet connection. Switched to WiFi & tried sudo apt-get update and it worked fine.

Possibly you just need to set up the ethernet connection to enable internet access
